# Converting large Joomla site to WP Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I am new to Multisites installations - and I think have a bit of a (long) &  complicated list of questions (10)  - please bear with me as it may not be as complicated as I think it is and I apologize in advance for the length as I am not sure where else to ask this.

I may be over explaining a bit but I am not sure how to setup properly for stability and ease of use for the client

I am also happy to offer some compensation for someone's time to get me moving in the right direction if the below is too confusing  - most of the installations are done but the next steps are what I am not sure about ( domain mapping? Sub directories? Sub domains?)

---

Some information:

1. Our Current site is a very old Joomla installation ( v1.5) and we are not converting or exporting data ( at least i don't think so - everything in the new site will be manually recreated)
2. It will be ( its installed already) a fresh new WP Multisites install in a new directory so we don't have to put the current site down until ready to launch
3. Our Current site is at "site.com" and the new multisite install is here "site.com/multi"
4. The main site's other "branches" or sites ( there are 12 of them) are sub-domains that are pointing to sub directories and redirecting to HTML pages

   IE: ( within cpanel sub domains area)

   (A) Branch1.site.com (has a document root directory on the server as  public_html/branch1 ) and redirects to Site.com/branches/branch1.html

   (B) Branch2.site.com (has a document root directory on the server as  public_html/branch2 ) and redirects to Site.com/branches/branch2.html

   (C)  Branch3.site.com (has a document root directory on the server as  public_html/branch3 ) and redirects to Site.com/branches/branch3.html

   (D) Branch4.site.com (has a document root directory on the server as  public_html/branch4 ) and redirects to Site.com/branches/branch4.html

Etc

5. Now I as I said above we don't want to disrupt the existing current site above until the new install is all setup and done
6. Now my question is

I have installed the new Multisites network here "site.com/multi" and within that wordpress install created the network of sites

multi/site1
Multi/site2
Multi/site3

Etc up to 12 of them

Now I don't have those directories manually created yet on the server

When I switch the site  over should the domains be mapped? 
Or should I just update the sub domains in cpanel?

Or should the sites just be subdirectories ?
( is it better to have sub domains or sub directories with a Wordpress Multisite?)

(remembering that they are sub domains currently being redirected to sub directories on the Joomla site)

7. We also need each branch manager to be able to login to their own branch site and manage it( but not be a master admin - only an admin on their own site)

( noting that when site is ready to launch we will be moving wp-config and index.php so that this site launches at the root)

Ie

so will it (login be for each site)be ?

site.com/multi/branch1/wp-login.php 
Or
Site.branch1.com/wp-login.php
or 
branch1.site.com/wp-login.php

Or will everyone login at a master login with their own user admin for that site?

Site.com/multi/wp-login.php

User: branch1_admin ; branch2_admin; branch3_admin. Etc etc?

All sites will be using same commercial theme and plugins - all they will have access to is updating their page content and maybe updating some plugins

So as you can see I am not sure if I am over complicating things or not

9. Also this being a rather large non profit site - each site also has to support independent embedded iframe scripts ( that's 12 different scripts - think pet adoption related) 
   Does Multisites have a problem with multiple iframe scripts or is that a non-issue?
10. Also this may or may not be relevant to note but we may be moving the site to a new host after all this is complete ( another cPanel site) but don't want to alert the current host

hence why we are building the site quietly in a sub directory 
( there's a matter of many emails using DNS hosting pointing elsewhere)

Would it be better to setup the hosting on a new server first and build the Multisite there?

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Lerosia

Comment: Lerosia, you really need to understand that everything is _trial and error_ with computing, development and sys administration, and you haven't tried yet. At Stackoverflow, we help people debugging and solving problems in their code and these questions are much more suitable to ask Wordpress support team. You can also Google Wordpress Multisite setup and you'll get started. I know you're new here, but try yourself forth and see where you end up, you'll learn much more from that instead of me writing a 1K mockup for how to do it, and if you stumble upon _errors_ you are free to ask them here.

Comment: Hmm exactly the kind of answer I wasn't going for but thank you Sven - and not sure what you mean by haven't tried yet - I am an experienced developer but just am not sure about the Multisites setup - and perhaps I over explained and apologized for but there were many questions on this site about domain mapping sub domains and sub directories and I assumed this might be the place to get answers  that is all